# Check on Page_Load which item was clicked on a ResultsRepeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, repeater

I know this is a pretty strange question but I need to know which item was clicked before the click event fires on the repeater.

This will tell me that it was the repeater that is doing the post back, but not which item was clicked:

```
Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString()
```

How do I find out which repeater item was clicked?
If it helps, here is the markup for the repeater in full.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ResultsRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" width="360">
            <tr bgcolor="#d5d5e6">
                <th width="10">
                    &nbsp;
                </th>
                <th>
                    Content Type
                </th>
                <th>
                    Items Found
                </th>
                <th>
                    Results
                </th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr bgcolor="#efefef">
            <td width="10">
                <img src="http://www.exactmobile.co.za/images/li_x.gif">
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name") %>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <b class="brown">
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Count") %></b>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Results">Show <font class="red">»</font></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <td width="10">
                <img src="http://www.exactmobile.co.za/images/li_x.gif">
            </td>
            <td>
                <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Name") %>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <b class="brown">
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Count") %></b>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Results">Show <font class="red">»</font></asp:LinkButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting up event handlers for each of your link button controls? If not, doing that might as well take you exactly to respective event handler automatically.

Also see if this helps [ASP.NET - Add Event Handler to LinkButton inside of Repeater in a RenderContent call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122821/asp-net-add-event-handler-to-linkbutton-inside-of-repeater-in-a-rendercontent-c)

Comment: Don't want to use the event handlers at all in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Worked around the issue by just using normal anchors in the template and setting their hrefs to the actual pages in the controls Pre_Render method.